# What is an ias-web.xml deployment descriptor file?

Tags: java, xml, web-applications, servlets, configuration

I came across a fairly old Java web application that made use of servlets and along side the web.xml file in the WEB-INF directory there was an `ias-web.xml` file.  From googling a bit I found it is some kind of a deployment descriptor file.

But when would you have one?  Are they still in use today?  Did this use to be a Java standard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ias is an old App server. And like all app servers, there are default descriptors like web.xml and vendor specific files like `ias-web.xml`.

This comes from the fact that the JavaEE standard specifies a lot, but still leaves room for vendor specific 
enhancements. And those enhancements are controlled by the vendor-speficic descriptors. The counterpart of ias-web.xml on JBoss would for example be `jboss-web.xml`

Have a look at [this guide](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aZb5oHFABPp8J%3adocs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/819-3663/6n5sag7gr%3Fl%3Dko%26a%3Dview+ias-web.xml&cd=1&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&client=safari&source=www.google.de) about migration hints.

Comment: After some additional googling, I found it was the IPlanet web application server as found here:  http://www.oracle.com/us/products/middleware/application-server/050735.html